materials not showing in cycles with motion tracking
Hi guys I was following a tutorial to do a motion tracking thing to make a hologram vfx on my phone. When I was rendering the scene in  EEVEE, everything looks just fine. But as I switched to Cycles the materials are not rendered properly.
I was trying to find a solution for several hours but still can't make it right.



